# Starscream Swift connecting to localhost socket does nothing

Tags: swift, sockets, starscream

I am trying to connect to my localhost socket (which works fine) like this:

```
import Starscream    

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let conn = ConnectionManager()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    conn.startSession()
}

}


class ConnectionManager {

    let socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "ws://localhost:8080/")!)

    func startSession(){
        socket.delegate = self
        socket.connect()
    }
}

extension ConnectionManager: WebSocketDelegate{
    func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocket) {
        print("connected")
    }

    func websocketDidDisconnect(socket: WebSocket, error: NSError?) {

    }

    func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocket, text: String) {
        print("text")
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocket, data: Data) {

    }

//put the delegate methods here
```

}

However in my server it does not notify me that a new connection has been made. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where you socket instance is allocated? If you make an alloc in the method, it might become nil. You should set instance inside your class globally and then set the delegate in a connection method. That should work.

Comment: I am very new to swift. Could you please provide a brief example @Woof

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import Starscream
class ConnectionManager {

let socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "ws://localhost:8080/")!)

func startSession(){
     socket.delegate = self
     socket.connect()
}

}

extension ConnectionManager: WebSocketDelegate{
        //put the delegate methods here
}
```

Comment: The delegate should provide to you the result of the connection. And you can detect what is going on with your connection

Comment: Works great however the delegate functions arent working. It is not displaying my print statements onConnect and onDidReceiveData @Woof

Comment: Did you make any print of an error inside the delegate method webSocketDidDisconnect? What is the output in your console in the time of connection attempt?

Comment: I made a print of an error and there is absolutely nothing in my console. Its not displaying yet there is no error @Woof

Comment: Add socket.selfSignedSSL = true to the connection method. Might helps

Comment: socket doesn't have `.selfSignedSSL` @Woof

Comment: Also you can find the method connec() in the ws framework class and set the breakpoint there to check the method execution line by line

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant socket.disableSSLValidation = true.

Comment: Any luck with debugging the connect() method? Was it called at least?

Comment: If I add a breakpoint at socket.delegate = self it says that delegate = nil @Woof

Comment: The delegate functions are unreachable no matter what I do. I am not sure what the issue is

Comment: If you've added the breakpoint to the line where the delegate is been set, it will be nil, you need to add the breakpoint under that line. It should not be nil. But I asked to add the breakpoint inside the method connect() in the framework class. Did you make it? Was that method called?

Comment: Something is wrong for sure. It should be called. Confirm please: the method startSession is being called, right? So the socket is not nil in the line where you are calling socket.connect(), right? If both your answers will be yes, then send me the screenshot where you've put the breakpoint in the framework class

Comment: startSession is called and socket.connect is called, in my socket server it tells me that a connection has been made. It is just the delegate functions that aren't called

Comment: Ok, let's try to check the state. In the viewDidAppear method check conn.socket.isConnected and conn.socket.delegate using print()

Comment: conn.socket.delegate prints Optional(SocketTrial.ConnectionManager)
conn.socket.isConnected prints false

Comment: So the delegate is set, but the socket is not connecting. That's why we need to check what is going with the connection in the method connect() and all related methods. Also you might need to check your server requirements for additional headers and parameters to set them for the socket. And it will be good if you have an ability to test connections using third party applications, like Postman(not sure if it has this ability, but it should)

Comment: Think my server works fine because I have a fully working chat application with it I was just trying to implement it in Swift. Whenever I start my app my server console displays this `GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Origin: ws://localhost:8080
Sec-WebSocket-Key: ZmRqYXZwdXFub2RkcW1peQ==` meaning that a conncetion has been made

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea why it doesn't work for you. I have the same code in my current project (my socket has some additional headers also to connect to the server) and it works perfectly for me, also there was a question few days ago with the same problem, and it was solved by that code to. And we've also checked that the delegate has been set and the socket is starting to connect. The only thing that you can make - look deeper through the framework methods and try to debug it line by line. Will be sad, if we both missing something, hope you will find the answer.